# Powershell script, Trying to use WMIObject -Class to get a group component keeps coming up with invalid query

Tags: powershell

Working in Powershell, trying to set variable

```
$admin = Get-WMIObject -CLass "Win32_GroupUser"  -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "GroupComponent = '$($admins.__Path)'"
```

Keep getting error:

```
Invalid query *select * from Win32_GroupUser where GroupComponent + ' '". Error Message: + ...    $admin = Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_GroupUser" -ComputerName $Pc  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Help me understand why it's not connecting to my query?

I've tried to use different class instances CMI instance, and I've used AI to explain the problem. I believe it's the architecture in which it's written. The regex pattern needs to be modified is my guess.

Comment: What is `$admins`?

Comment: It's a variable that is supposed to store the admins found in CM -> Local Administrators and $admin should grab one admin from $admins

Comment: Well, `$admins.__Path` clearly expands to a single whitespace character, so it obviously isn't behaving as you expect. Can you show us the code you used to obtain the value stored in `$admins`?

Comment: foreach($computer in $Computers) {
          #Write-Host "Computer: $($computer.name)"
          $Pc = $computer.CN 
          $Desc = $computer.Description 
          if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Pc -Count 1 -Quiet)#This is returning a failed test connection for some reason 
          {Write-Host "Checking $computer..."
           #Query WMI for local admin group
           $admins = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "Domain='$domain'"
           #If admin group exists, loop through members and add to results
            if($admins)

Comment: As an aside, the WMI commands are deprecated. They are not even in PowerShell Core (6.x+). Better to move to the, almost identical, CIM commands. Yes, it still uses WMI internally.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to loop over the group objects and query the relationships for 1 group at a time:

```
$groups = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "Domain='$domain'"

foreach ($group in $groups) {
  Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "GroupComponent = '$($group.__Path)'"
}
```

---

Your original query would have succeeded if you update the filter to describe exactly 1 group:

```
$builtinAdminGroup = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "Domain = '$domain' AND SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'"

# this now works 
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Pc -Filter "GroupComponent = '$($builtinAdminGroup.__Path)'"
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I get it to point directly to the administrators group to save the program time from iterating through each group? Note* I'm extremely new to Powershell so thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mr.Mauve WQL (the query language for WMI) allows you to specify [multiple clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/where-clause) separated with `AND`/`OR` keywords: eg. `-Filter "Domain = '$domain' AND SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'"` (`S-1-5-32-544` is the well-known static SID for the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group in any Windows SAM database)